# Does all inbuilt writables use default raw comparator?

Tags: hadoop

I am just confused that does all inbuilt writables like IntWritable, FloatWritable, GenericWritable etc. uses raw comparator for comparison by default? If not, how should we register them to use rawcomparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to get the `RawComparator` is in [JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.java#JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator%28%29):

```
  public RawComparator getOutputKeyComparator() {
    Class<? extends RawComparator> theClass = getClass("mapred.output.key.comparator.class",
            null, RawComparator.class);
    if (theClass != null)
      return ReflectionUtils.newInstance(theClass, this);
    return WritableComparator.get(getMapOutputKeyClass().asSubclass(WritableComparable.class));
  }
```

Hadoop will try to get the `RawComparator` class name from `mapred.output.key.comparator.class`. If it's not set, hadoop will try to convert the key class to `WritableComparable`, and use it to create a `WritableComparator`. So if we do not set our customer `RawComparator`, we enter [WritableComparator.get](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparator.java#WritableComparator.get%28java.lang.Class%29).

```
  public static synchronized 
  WritableComparator get(Class<? extends WritableComparable> c) {
    WritableComparator comparator = comparators.get(c);
    if (comparator == null) {
      // force the static initializers to run
      forceInit(c);
      // look to see if it is defined now
      comparator = comparators.get(c);
      // if not, use the generic one
      if (comparator == null) {
        comparator = new WritableComparator(c, true);
      }
    }
    return comparator;
  }
```

In `WritableComparator.get`, it will search the `WritableComparator` in a map `comparators` at first.

Most built in `Writable`s, such as IntWritable, when they are loaded, they will invoke `define` to put their `WritableComparator` (e.g., `org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable.Comparator`) to the `comparators`. So if you want to register your custom `RawComparator`, you can use codes like (You need to make sure these codes are in your `Writable` class body):

```
  static {                                        // register this comparator
    WritableComparator.define(IntWritable.class, new Comparator());
  }
```

Next, what happens if a `WritableComparable` does not register a `WritableComparator`? That's the default behaviors of [WritableComparator](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparator.java#WritableComparator.compare%28byte%5B%5D,int,int,byte%5B%5D,int,int%29). It will invoke the `WritableComparable.compareTo` to compare two keys.